# Unioning Two Tables and Selection Only Top 'n' Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

I'm trying to write a social networking application but I'm stuck with the wall posts/comments part. I have two tables, **POSTS** and **COMMENTS**;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COMMENTS](
    [COMMENT_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [POST_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [USER_ID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [COMMENT] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CREATED] [datetime]
)
-- COMMENT_ID is PK

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POSTS](
    [POST_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [USER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [POST] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CREATED] [datetime]
)
-- POST_ID is PK
```

What I'm trying to do is to select **TOP N** records from **POSTS** table and all of comments belong to those records. I'm using the following query but it selects all records from POSTS and COMMENTS, which slows down the server as there are so many POSTS

```
SELECT POST_ID, NULL AS COMMENT_ID, USER_ID, POST, CREATED, POST_ID AS SEQUENCE FROM POSTS
UNION
SELECT POST_ID, COMMENT_ID, USER_ID, COMMENT AS POST, CREATED, POST_ID AS SEQUENCE FROM COMMENTS
ORDER BY SEQUENCE DESC
```

How can select TOP 10 POSTS and all comments to those posts? I would also like to dbpage those records, so maybe a paging code would be great for me. I mean instead of selecting top 10 posts, I would like to select 10 POSTS from page 2 and their comments.

I'm not sure if this is possible with this table structure. If it's not, maybe you should offer me a better table structure.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I want the recordset be like below. I think the below table is better than INNER JOIN-ed table. All I want is to **SELECT TOP N POSTS**, nothing more.

```
POST_ID     | COMMENT_ID    | USER_ID   | POST                          | CREATED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3               NULL            2           This post has no comments       2011-02-12
1               NULL            1           A new post                      2011-02-11
1               1               2           Comment for post 1              2011-02-11
1               2               1           Another comment for post 1      2011-02-11
1               5               2           Another comment for post 1      2011-02-11
2               NULL            2           Another post                    2011-02-07
2               3               1           Comment for post 2              2011-02-07
2               4               2           Another comment for post 2      2011-02-07
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select post_id, comment_id, user_id, post, created
from (
    select top 10 post_id, null as comment_id, user_id, post, created
    from posts
    order by created desc
    ) ss

union

select 
    posts.post_id
    , comment_id
    , comments.user_id
    , comment as post
    , comments.created
from posts
inner join comments on posts.post_id = comments.post_id
where posts.post_id in (
    select top 10 post_id
    from posts
    order by created desc
    )

order by created desc
```

Comment: +1 because this will work for the top 10 but won't take into account pagination.

Comment: Well your query gives only comments in a single a row but not posts. I use UNION because I want to list posts and comments as separate rows. When I run your query, POST field is repeated in every record, which I think that might not be effective as POST field might contain long text. And what about POSTS that don't have any comments yet? It seems like this query is not what I want. I will edit my question to give some more details about the recordset.

Comment: @Kakao That was so close but this only comments, but other posts are not displayed. If the latest post has no comments, then it's also included too, but no other POST info is displayed. Btw you query is not working, so I changed it like; SELECT 
    POSTS.POST_ID
    , COMMENTS.COMMENT_ID
    , POSTS.USER_ID
    , CASE WHEN COMMENTS.COMMENT IS NULL THEN POSTS.POST ELSE COMMENTS.COMMENT END AS POST
    , POSTS.CREATED
FROM POSTS
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMMENTS ON POSTS.POST_ID = COMMENTS.POST_ID
WHERE POSTS.POST_ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 10 POST_ID
    FROM POSTS
    ORDER BY CREATED DESC
    )

Comment: @Burak - Changed again. BTW the user_id column in the comments table is not necessary as it exists in the related post.

Comment: @Kakao - This works perfect. I changed column names, as it was not working with lowercase field names. And it works now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Kakao - Btw "id" field must be "post_id" as I don't have an "id" field in posts table. Thanks again.

Comment: @Burak - changed post.user_id to comments.user_id in the second select

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` (and `UNION ALL`) gives you the combined result of two completely separate `SELECT` queries, which probably is not quite what you want with that last code snippet.

> How can select TOP 10 POSTS and all comments to those posts?

I would imagine that a simple `INNER JOIN` from `POSTS` to `COMMENTS` should be a good start. Not sure how to best implement paging in such a scenario, though.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding pagination, I think you'll need to use `ROW_NUMBER()` - [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) - to create a count based on your `POST_ID`. That way you can select ranges dynamically at query time.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT POST_ID, NULL AS COMMENT_ID, USER_ID, POST, CREATED, POST_ID AS SEQUENCE FROM POSTS
UNION
SELECT POST_ID, COMMENT_ID, USER_ID, COMMENT AS POST, CREATED, POST_ID AS SEQUENCE FROM COMMENTS
ORDER BY SEQUENCE DESC
WHERE (POSTS.POST_ID IN (SELECT TOP (10) POST_ID FROM POSTS as POSTS1))
```

Allso I dont understand why you are using Union over Inner Join. You might want to try it out too.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to get both POSTS and COMMENTS with INNER JOIN as INNER JOIN will repeat POST field for every COMMENT. So I decided to use UNION instead of INNER JOIN, but I'm not sure if I'm right. Btw, your query gives "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'" error.

Answer (score 0):

Join two tables and retrieve top 10 records

select top 10 * from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.empid=Table2.empid